Failed to load dynamic library 'pdfrx.dll': The specified module could not be found flutter
I am using pdfrx package to read pdf file as:
_document = await PdfDocumentFactory.instance.openCustom(read:read,sourceName: file.path, fileSize: filesize );
Its throwing exception on
final interopLib = DynamicLibrary.open(_getModuleFileName()); <- this line
// it's trying to find the pdfrx.dll file but I couldn't find any file generated with pdfrx.dll name.

String _getModuleFileName() {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) return 'libpdfrx.so';
  if (Platform.isIOS || Platform.isMacOS) return 'pdfrx.framework/pdfrx';
  if (Platform.isWindows) return 'pdfrx.dll';
  if (Platform.isLinux) {
    return '${File(Platform.resolvedExecutable).parent.path}/lib/libpdfrx.so';
  }
  throw UnsupportedError('Unsupported platform');
}


There is CMakeList file in src directory as:

add_library(pdfrx SHARED
  "pdfium_interop.cpp"
)

set_target_properties(pdfrx PROPERTIES
  OUTPUT_NAME "pdfrx"
)

target_compile_definitions(pdfrx PUBLIC DART_SHARED_LIB)

Could anybody help to generate this dll file?

@KJ Thank you for the comment. I will look into your suggestions.
